# How to send a message to all logged in users on a server/s i.e. Warning: Server/s going down for maintenance

Tags: c#, angular, azure, web-applications, azure-active-directory

I am looking for a way to be able to push a notification to all users in an environment/server based on certain actions such as:

1. A warning telling all logged in users that the server will be going down at x time for an update,
2. A notification for users logging in for the first time after an update containing update notes so they can see what has changed

Currently my application is spread over several environments. Is there a way to push a message to all of them simultaneously?

I have created a web app with the below specs:

Frontend - Angular 6

Backend - .net/c#

Hosted - Azure

What would be the best way to achieve this? Can you point me in the direction of a resource that will help me learn how to do this? Any advice would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at SignalR.. your own implementation or using Azure Service https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/

Comment: Azure notifications hub  (similar to  amazon SNS)

Comment: Unless I have read incorrectly Azure Notifications is aimed exclusively at mobiles and not for web applications sadly